# Get first post from wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop

How can I get the first post from a WP_Query result?

```
$connected = new WP_Query( array(
// Arguments
));

// This doesn't work..
echo $connected[0]->post_name;
```

Comment: You must use a loop. Read the codex entry on WP_Query..there's an [example loop there](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage). Additionally in the same page you can find the [`posts_per_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) parameter and limit the query to retrieve only 1 post.

Comment: @helgatheviking Yes I know that it's possible that way, But so it is not possible without the loop?

Comment: You can use `get_post()` [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) or use [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) like the commentor above suggests, and if you still need the first post you can alwyas rewind your query - `$connected->rewind_posts()`

Comment: Try $connected->posts[0]->post_name - $connected is an WP_Query object which contains a posts array member.

Comment: Everything is possible, but why reinvent the wheel? `var_dump($connected)` to see why what you've proposed doesn't work. `$connected` is actually an object with the resulting posts actually in the `$connected->posts` property.

Comment: Thanks you all for help. `$connected->posts[0]->post_name` did the job!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you poke through `WP_Query` the set of queried posts is saved into `posts` property and current post gets assigned to `post` one (each time loop iterates).

So you could do `$connected->posts[0]` if you need to just fetch that, but it might be more convenient to do `$connected->the_post();` then `$connected->post` if you need to skip first one and process the rest in normal loop.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a code like this:

```
if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
  $first_post = $the_query->posts[0];
  echo "1st post title\t:"$first_post->post_title;
}
```